# Import to Google Sheets - possible to change import location default?

Tags: google-sheets, import

In Google Sheets, under "File-->Import" - I don't really understand why the import location default is "Create new spreadsheet" and not "Insert new sheet(s)" (see image).

After all, I entered a specific spreadsheet for a reason..

Is there a way to change the default? (trying to save clicks and human errors).

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There is no way to change that default.

I believe this is the default because its similar to what you might expect in a desktop application (at least that is my experience). Though depending on what you are used to, it may not make sense.

If you'd like to request the ability to change the default you should send feedback here:

[image]

#### Ideas for workarounds

- You could try and write a [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) to auto-select that option.
- You could write some [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or even an [Add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview) to always follow your specific workflow.

I believe looking into Apps Script will be your best bet for streamlining situations where every click counts and where human-error might be common. For these types of things, scripting really is the best way because it gives you almost total control of the workflow and allows you to automate almost everything.

#### Example

If you have a csv file in your drive, you can use a function like this to parse the data and get it in a 2D array, similar to when you use `getValues` on a Spreadsheet range:

```js
function getCsvDataFromDrive(fileId) {
  const csv = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)
  const text = csv.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  const data = Utilities.parseCsv(text)
  console.log(data)
}
```

You just pass the fileID into the function and it will log a 2D array of the data.

#### References

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob())
- [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob#getDataAsString())
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))

Comment: Thanks, I am very familiar with Google Apps Scripts. Though I did not find a built-in GAS methods for Sheets that handles the import workflow

Comment: There is nothing built-in, but it is possible to do with CSV data. I will edit and leave a suggestion in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your elaborated answer! However, the CSV/Excel file isn’t in my drive in advance, as your example scenario suggests. The upload only takes place via the import screen. Uploading to the drive, then copy the ID, then going back to the sheet and insert the ID for the function to use takes more clicks and risk more human errors (not tech savvy users). I will file a suggestion though :)

Comment: I appreciate that, it was just an example. For your solution there would have to be many other parts. There are ways to show a "picker" dialogue for instance, and I would be happy to help further, however, I think that is out of scope of this question which was originally about the menu default which I believe I answered.

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks again